# Index data with Solr PHP Client

Tags: php, solr

I'm using the `Solr PHP Client` and have the `Solr 4.3.0` example up and running. I have not modified the `schema.xml` file. When I run this code I get a `400` error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message '400' Status: Bad Request.'
```

The document does not show up in the index. Interestingly, If I restart `Jetty`, the document is indexed. Here's my code. I was wondering if I'm missing something. I thought this was an issue with my input matching the schema, but `id` seems to be the only required field and these other fields are in the schema. I'm not sure what to do.

```
require_once('SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php');

$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', 8983, '/solr/');

if($solr->ping() == null){
    die('could not ping solr');
}

$document = new Apache_Solr_Document();
$document->id = 'guid1';
$document->title = 'Title1';
$document->subject = 'The subject is solr';
$document->description = 'This is the description';

$solr->addDocument($document);
$solr->commit();
```

The full error message I get is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''400' Status: Bad Request' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php:364 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php(829): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawPost('http://localhos...', '<commit expunge...', 3600)  
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\indexerSOLR_PHP.php(20): Apache_Solr_Service->commit()  
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php on line 364`
```

Comment: I am using the same code to commit my data but still unable to search it on the Solr Admin. If you are through with this, can you help me out please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with Solr 4.x and calling commit from the Solr PHP Client. Please see 
[Bug #62332 - As of solr 4.0 the waitFlush parameter is removed for commit](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62332) for the details and a patch to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I apply the patch? Is this a shell script I can run if i change the extension name? And to be clear, the Solr-PHP-client is what get's patched, yes? Not Solr, correct?

Comment: Oh its the PECL Solr PHP extension that get's patch. This seems like its going to be complicated though.. :(

Comment: Looks like you can compare your Service.php file with this one that has the necessary changes https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/source/browse/trunk/Apache/Solr/Service.php#821 and just modify your local copy.

Answer (score 2):

That is what how I got the solution, I modified commit method. Added '&commit=true' to the _updateurl variable.

```
public function commit($expungeDeletes = false, $waitFlush = true, $waitSearcher = true, $timeout = 3600)
{
    $expungeValue = $expungeDeletes ? 'true' : 'false';
    $flushValue = $waitFlush ? 'true' : 'false';
    $searcherValue = $waitSearcher ? 'true' : 'false';

    //$rawPost = '<commit expungeDeletes="' . $expungeValue . '" waitFlush="' . $flushValue . '" waitSearcher="' . $searcherValue . '" />';
            //$this->post=$rawPost;        
    return $this->_sendRawGet($this->_updateUrl.'&commit=true', $timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have change this line.

require_once('SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php'); => require_once('Service.php');

Maybe Service.php this file's path wrong. I try to changed this line. Then work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I have installed an old version of the PHP Solr extension (0.9.11).

To get a the latest one:

```
pecl download solr-beta
tar xvzf solr-2.1.0.tgz # This can be different depending on the last release number
cd solr-2.1.0/
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
# add extension=solr.so to your php.ini / distribution extension loader
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733513/1145134).