# pecl/solr cant seem to install normaly

Tags: php, apache, solr, pecl

I'm trying to connect to my Solr server trough PHP. I got a tutorial that users the SolrClient(). My but this was not available on my Linux (ubuntu) server. Now I'm trying to install it to my apache. The problem is that I cant seem to get the extensions working. I am trying to get it through `sudo pecl install solr-beta`. But this keeps giving the following error: Download of "pecl/solr" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive.

So my question is how can this be when this is according to most tutorials the only way i can get this extention of apache? And how do I get this working. I'm realy stuk.

Ohh I have tried to get it trough download but the necessary files are missing to configure and use make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need phpize installed if you try to download the archive by yourself. If you have `phpize` installed, the way to do this manually:

```
pecl download solr-beta
tar xvzf solr-2.0.0.tgz
cd solr-2.0.0
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
# add extension=solr.so to your php.ini / distribution extension loader
```

.. this should be the same as doing `pecl install solr-beta`, so if that fails you'll at least be able to see where in the chain any issues arise. A complete log of the pecl session might be useful to debug it any further.

Comment: Tnx that at least got pecl working :) any idea why this isn't resolving the `PHP Fatal error: Class 'SolrClient'`?

Comment: You'll have to be sure to add extension=.. to your php.ini (or /etc/php5/conf.d/solr.ini or similar, depending on your distribution). Check that the extension is loaded in the ouput from phpinfo();, and be sure to use \SolrClient if you're in a custom namespace.